# a tag link doesn't work when a user clicks on its nested label tag

Tags: html, css

**PROBLEM** is really simple.

I wrapped a `label` tag and `span` tag with a tag and put `href` property on the anchor tag. But in IE browser ( not tested in the older versions ), the link doesn't work when I click on the label tag. ( Chrome works, FYI)

**REPRODUCTION**

```css
span, label {

  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  
}

span {
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  background:url("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=c4222387135a");
}

label {
  height:50px;  
  font-size:37pt;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<a href="/#">

  <span></span><label>This is my logo</label>
  
</a>

<br/><br/>

<div style="width:160px; background-color:green; display:inline-block; color:white; height:22px; padding:15px; text-align:center;">Working zone</div>
<div style="width:300px; background-color:#ccc; display:inline-block; color:white; height:22px; padding:15px; text-align:center;">Not working zone</div>
```

**THREE QUESTIONS**

1. How can I make the link work.
2. Why the link doesn't work on only the label tag when it's completely wrapped around by the anchor tag?
3. Why my cursor loses the `pointer` shape on the nested label tag?

Comment: You should not combine a link and a label. They both react to click events, but they have different purposes. Combining them needlessly results in bad user experience. Make up your mind about what UI interaction you want, and use either a link or a label. If you need both things, create label and a link separately.

Comment: Works for me as far back as IE8...

Comment: @Tomalak I simply didn't know when to use label tags. Thanks!! and sily for my stupidity :[

Comment: See [MDN on `<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure is abnormal. If you want your label to be a link, then modify the structure this way -

```
 <label>
    <a href="/#">This is my logo</a>
 </label>
```

What is your aim behind using `label` this way? Labels are mostly used with input controls.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge. No purpose of using label is behind. I was just stupid : [

Answer (score 1):

Use only span tag. You don't need to have a label inside span. This code will work in all browsers.

```
<a href="/#">

  <span>This is my logo</span>

</a>
```

Apply styles accordingly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple assign cursor: pointer in the css of the label tag

```
label
{
cursor:pointer;
}
```